# Tkinter Contextual Menus Unexpected Behavior on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, tkinter, contextmenu, tkinter-canvas

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk        

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

id = canvas.create_rectangle((20, 20, 40, 40), fill="red")

menu = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
menu.add_command(label='Options')

def do_linkpopup(event):
    try:
        menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    finally:
        menu.grab_release()

canvas.tag_bind(id, "<Button-3>", lambda e: do_linkpopup(e))
root.mainloop()
```

It works fine on Windows. When I right-click on rectangle, the menu pops up and remains visible until I click anywhere else. But on Ubuntu 16.04, the menu doesn't close when clicking elsewhere.

I have seen some examples where they use 'tk_popup()' with third parameter set to '0':

```
menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
```

I tried this approach and the problem with this method is that the menu immediately closes on right-click release.

Accidentally, I found that calling 'grab_release()' on 'root' instead of 'menu' solves this problem:

```
root.grab_release()
```

But I can't find any reasonable explanation for this.

Does anyone have any explanation or other solution for this issue?

Best Regards.